# How do I deploy a pure HTML/Javascript project in Websphere AS 7?

Tags: jakarta-ee, websphere-7

is there a way to just upload a folder or zip file with a bunch of html pages in WAS 7 without creating a WAR file?

I want to do this just in my development environment, so I don't have to setup/run a separate web server.

Comment: You would need to wrap the files in a [WAR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAR_%28file_format%29) file which can contain only static resources if you choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is not, you cannot deploy only html in WAS 7 , you would need to do it in the web server.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach your project to existing ear/war file which is deployed in the WAS 7. Modify the deployment descriptor of the EAR and add your project by selecting **manage utility jars**.